# Kivy variable background widget

Tags: android, python, kivy

I recently started using kivy, and I have a question about the change of the background.
I need to create multiple widgets with different backgrounds.
I'm doing it wrong, but I did not get:

```
Kv file:
<MyWidget@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: self.rgb
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
main.py
widget = Widget()
myWidget1 = Factory.MyWidget(rgb=[1,0,0])
myWidget2 = Factory.MyWidget(rgb=[0,1,0])
myWidget3 = Factory.MyWidget(rgb=[0,0,1])
widget.add_widget(myWidget1)
widget.add_widget(myWidget2)
widget.add_widget(myWidget3)
```

How can I make it better?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong here? Problems include that you don't declare an rgb property, and that it's not clear when you instantiate the widgets (which may or may not be after their kv is loaded).

Comment: The problem is that what I have written above does not work, I'd be grateful if you write to me how to do it.

Comment: Wen asking a question, you should specify not just that it doesn't work, but *how* it doesn't work - does it run but do something you don't expect? Does it crash? How does it crash? Do you get an error message? It is also good form to provide a runnable example if possible.

Comment: There is a fatal error when I try to run it, AttributeError: 'MyWidget' object has no attribute 'rgb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments above say, the problem is that MyWidget doesn't have an 'rgb' attribute (nor does a BoxLayout).

In the python file, you need to create the class with that attribute. Specifically, you should create a ListProperty attribute so that all the automatic binding on the kv side happens.

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyWidget(Boxlayout):
    rgb = ListProperty([0,0,0])
```